# Computer wifi keeps disconnecting

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, linux-mint

I have an Asus laptop and have always had problems with WiFi disconnecting suddenly and the list of available networks being empty. When I had Windows 10, restarting the computer would fix it but it was a hassle to do this almost every day. I switched to Linux Mint and didn't have this problem for some days, but after a few updates and downloads, the WiFi started disconnecting again. However, even when I use a USB to live boot to Linux Mint, the WiFi connects only for a short time. I'm not sure if this is a software or hardware issue. I'm thinking of buying a USB WiFi adapter but I'm not even sure that will fix it.

On Linux Mint, sometimes the option to connect to WiFi isn't there at all and the output for `rfkill list` is only bluetooth connections until I restart or do a live USB boot.

I know this isn't a router problem because all other devices at home work and the laptop disconnects from the WiFi at my college too.

Comment: Using a USB WiFi adapter will tell you if this is hardware or not. If it works it might even become a solution.

Comment: Using a USB WiFi adapter worked. Thanks.

Comment: I had a very similar experience with an ASUS laptop too. Turned out the wifi hardware was broken; I bought a new one off the internet for 5$ and it works great. If you know how to use a screwdriver, it is not too bad to install it yourself, and worth the try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As using a USB WiFi adapter worked, this is not an operating system problem
but is probably an intermittent hardware problem with the internal WiFi adapter.

You might, if you can, open up the laptop and verify all connections.
But if you can see nothing, keeping on using the USB adapter is the
simplest solution to the problem.